# xelatex won't compile in texworks

Tags: xelatex, miktex, texworks

I can't get xelatex to compile anything in texworks. I just reinstalled miktex 21.6 on windows 10 and immediately updated packages without any errors. I can compile in pdflatex but not in xelatex and I can't figure out why. Thoughts?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World
\end{document}
```

TexWorks console output:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (MiKTeX 21.6.28)
entering extended mode
(untitled-1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-06-18>
(C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xet
ex.def
Sorry, but C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-xetex.exe did not succeed.
```

log:

```
INFO  miktex-xetex - this process (15336) started by 'miktex-texworks' with command line: C:\Users\crist\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-xetex.exe -synctex=1 -undump=xelatex untitled-5.tex
INFO  miktex-xetex - allowing known shell commands
INFO  miktex-xetex - executing input pipe: extractbb "--version"
INFO  miktex-xetex.core - starting input pipe: extractbb "--version"
FATAL miktex-xetex.core - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
FATAL miktex-xetex.core - Data: 
FATAL miktex-xetex.core - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp:560
FATAL miktex-xetex - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
FATAL miktex-xetex - Info: 
FATAL miktex-xetex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\win\winProcess.cpp
FATAL miktex-xetex - Line: 560
INFO  miktex-xetex - this process (15336) finishes with exit code 1
```

So far I've reinstalled miktex, turned off virus protection, double checked that packages can be installed on the fly.

Comment: maybe you could ask at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues ?